# Calculate 9 to 5 hrs

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to calculate number of business hours between 2 days.

For eg.

```
A                   B
15/05/2013 13:25    31/05/2013 10:20
19/05/2013 09:12    22/05/2013 21:10
```

I want to get result in C column with possible following term..

```
6d 15h 20m
```

or anything similar to above. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. What should be the result of the first row in your example? `6d 15h 20m`? Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry Jerry. Yes that result i meant. I need total business hours in C column.(B-A) but i am completely unaware of the formula.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated than just an hours difference. Will you take into account weekends? Off days? Holidays? Or just the difference in hours? And btw, 6d 15h 20m is not a number of hours.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is presented on [this website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeWS.htm), and it involves quite a complex formula:

```
=IF(AND(INT(StartDT)=INT(EndDT),NOT(ISNA(MATCH(INT(StartDT),
HolidayList,0)))),"0 days 0 hours", IF(INT(StartDT)=INT(EndDT),
"0 days " & ROUND(24*(EndDT-StartDT),2)&"hours",
MAX(NETWORKDAYS(StartDT+1,EndDT-1,HolidayList),0)+
INT(24*(((EndDT-INT(EndDT))-(StartDT-INT(StartDT)))+
(DayEnd-DayStart))/(24*(DayEnd-DayStart)))&
" days "&MOD(ROUND(((24*(EndDT-INT(EndDT)))-24*DayStart)+
(24*DayEnd-(24*(StartDT-INT(StartDT)))),2),
ROUND((24*(DayEnd-DayStart)),2))&" hours "))
```

It assumes the following names:

- `StartDT`  – Starting date and time   (`25-Oct-99 13:00`)
- `EndDT`    – Ending date and time (`28-Oct-99 15:00`)
- `DayStart`     – Start of a work day (`9:00`)
- `DayEnd`   – End of a work day (`17:00`)
- `HolidayList`  – A range containing a list of dates to excluded

I can't test it as I don't have Excel, but it should get  the job done. Of course you can change the formula to achieve different output.

Comment: It did not return the value. It gives 0 days 0 hours

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for confirming this. I don't have Excel to try and change it, so if you can come up with a simple way to get the desired output, feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot arrive at your desired result in a single cell, but you can calculate the duration in C1 (assuming you're on row 1) using `=ABS(B1-A1)`. This will give you the number of days as a floating point value. You can then use other cells and formulas to divide that number into hours, minutes, and seconds, using `ROUNDDOWN()` to calculate integers.

---

Edit: Here are the contents of my example spreadsheet, since I can't seem to attach it here and I don't know what the policies are for linking to files that may or may not be there in the future. This calculates all time in the duration, not just 09:00 to 17:00 M–F. @slhck's answer may be more suitable.

Row 1:
(A) `Start`
(B) `Stop`
(C) `Days`
(D) `Hours`
(E) `Minutes`
(F) `Seconds`

Row 2:
(A) `5/1/2013 17:55:00`
(B) `6/3/2013 1:22:00`
(C) `=ROUNDDOWN(ABS(B2-A2))`
(D) `=ROUNDDOWN(((ABS(B2-A2))-C2)*24)`
(E) `=ROUNDDOWN(((((ABS(B2-A2))-C2)*24)-D2)*60)`
(F) `=((((((ABS(B2-A2))-C2)*24)-D2)*60)-E2)*60`

Comment: This question is probably about that second part you don't describe in detail. Example: Fri 5pm to Wed 5pm gives the same result as Mon 8am to Wed 5pm.

Comment: @DanielBeck I have updated my answer in response to your comment.